# git status displays crazy multiple levels of directories that don't exist

Tags: git

The git status command is showing this:

```
...
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
new file: DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/DirectoryA/FileA
```

and so on and so on.

I do have a directory within a directory with the same name, but only two levels deep, not dozens and dozens as git thinks.

What's the simplest way getting git back to a sane state, and how did it get like this?

Comment: The inner directory doesn't contain a link to the outer directory by any chance, does it? Because other than that, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, or that I have created.

Comment: Try running `git clean -f`.

Comment: No change after clean.

Comment: Could you post the output of `ls -l DirectoryA/DirectoryA`?

Comment: Sorry I've go two fed up with it I've deleted it and slowly recreating all my changes one by one from scratch again